# Left Join, Group By and Sum where related records don't exist

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
SELECT Table1.prod_code, SUM(Table1.prod_bal) AS TotalProdBalance
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.prod_code = Table2.prod_code
WHERE Table2.prod_code IS NULL
GROUP BY Table1.prod_code
HAVING (SUM(Table1.prod_bal) <> 0)
```

Could someone help me translate this to Linq using VB.net syntax?

Comment: You say "Could someone help me translate this to Linq using VB.net syntax?", how far have you got with converting the query to Linq and which part are you having problems with? SO is a question & answer site, not a translation service.

Comment: from what i understand in this code. It returns total product-balance difference by calculating the products which are not exist in the table2..


which means if i had 40 piece of 1box in my pocket and my name was TABLE1 and if hi2way got 30 piece of 1box in his/her pocket and his/her name was TABLE2, this code would give the result as 10 piece of 1box = 10box.. 

is this a good translation now? I dont think so but hope works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Check up this..

```
Dim query = (From rs1 in Table1
   Join rs2 In Table2 On rs1.prod_code Equals rs2.prod_code
   Group by record.prod_code Into TotalProdBalance = sum(rs1.prod_bal)
   Where rs2.prod_code Equals Null and TotalProdBalance <> 0
   Select rs1.prod_code, TotalProdBalance )
```